# How to connect python application with online database

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database-connection

I'm trying to connect Python Application with online database. It's working properly on localhost database but when I try to connect with online it showing error.

**Error**

```
errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '69.162.107.34:3306' (10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)
```

**Code**

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                host="00.00.00.00",
                user="user",
                passwd="pass",
                database="db"
            )

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94102/remote-mysql-connection-fails-10060-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-domain

Comment: You likely have a firewall on the remote server preventing direct connections to MySQL.  You probably don't want to open that firewall and make it accessible to all, though.  Take a look at SSH tunnelling if you're able to SSH into the MySQL machine or another machine that does have access.

Answer (score 0):

first connect with your workbench the try again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).